# Calculate power with very big exponents in java

Tags: java, pow, exponent

I have a problem in calculating the power of very big exponent. That is: i enter my password :`"abc"` then `calculate x=Hash(password)`. after that, i have to `calculate Y = pow(g,x)` in which, `g` is a `random numbe`r. So how can i calculate Y. Any suggestion ? thank you very much !

Comment: are you asking what datatype Y should be?. There's a pow method in java.lang.math.

Comment: read about `arbitrary precision arithmetic`

Comment: In fact, it is not really "pow". but i cannot express the formular. Can you see in this document: "Implementing Zero-Knowledge Authentication with Zero Knowledge (ZKA_wzk)"; link : http://ojs.pythonpapers.org/index.php/tppm/article/download/155/142    in page 9. I have to calculate Y. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cryptography `c = m^e (mod n)` where `c` is the cipher text, `n` is your max value that can be represented. Modulus operation is needed.

In addition to that, for large numbers exponentiation [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is used. `pow` operation implements this algorithm. Code is [here](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/StrictMath-source.html).

Cryptography implementation is much more complex, through, predefined byte arrays and byte operations. You can refer to [this paper's](http://www.mathaware.org/mam/06/Kaliski.pdf), **Modular Exponentiation and Roots** section.

Comment: In fact, it is not really "pow". but i cannot express the formular. Can you see in this document: "Implementing Zero-Knowledge Authentication with Zero Knowledge (ZKA_wzk)"; link : http://ojs.pythonpapers.org/index.php/tppm/article/download/155/142    in page 9. I have to calculate Y. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, you may want to look into BigInteger.modPow() method, more relevant than Math.pow() method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: In fact, it is not really "pow". but i cannot express the formular. Can you see in this document: "Implementing Zero-Knowledge Authentication with Zero Knowledge (ZKA_wzk)"; link : http://ojs.pythonpapers.org/index.php/tppm/article/download/155/142    in page 9. I have to calculate Y. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 10^100 is 100 digits. If your hash, lets say 4 billions, resulting value would consume 4Gb of memory. So your problem is barely solvable on a modern hardware.

Are you sure Y is pow(g,x) and not pow(g,x) mod SOME_VALUE? Then it'll make more sense.

Comment: In fact, it is not really "pow". but i cannot express the formular. Can you see in this document: "Implementing Zero-Knowledge Authentication with Zero Knowledge (ZKA_wzk)"; link : http://ojs.pythonpapers.org/index.php/tppm/article/download/155/142    in page 9. I have to calculate Y. thank you very much!